# How can I change the text size in Shiny modals?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I successfully changed the text sizes in shiny dashboard interface by editing css file.

Or I use following structure:

```
div(DTOutput(outputId = "table"), style = "font-size:85%"))
```

However, I couldn't find the node name of shiny modals. **Is it possible to change the text size in shiny modals through .css?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
        actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        observeEvent(input$show, {
            showModal(modalDialog(
                title = "Important message",
                div("This is an important message!", style="font-size:160%")
            ))
        })
    }
)
```

`ModalDialog` takes as its first argument(s) UI elements. This appears to be the same kind of arguments accepted by other shiny elements. Compare for example: `?siderbarPanel` and `?modalDialog`. So if you can do it in the body of an app, you can probably do it in a modal.

For example, I stuck a sidebar layout inside a modal:

```
shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
        actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        observeEvent(input$show, {
            showModal(modalDialog(
                sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel("yeah"),mainPanel("cool"))
            ))
        })
    }
)
```